# Please explain to me class delegation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, delegation

I don't understand the (BY) keyword in Kotlin like this:

```
interface a {
}

class b():a {
}

class c(x:a):a by x {
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've already read the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html), and want some more, I'll try to give you my explanation…

To show why delegation is needed, let's look at the main alternative.  And because your example is a little too simplified to demonstrate the issues, let's pick another one:

Suppose you need a class that behaves like (say) the stdlib `LinkedList`, but adds some extra behaviour.  (Say you need to log every item added to the list.)

The traditional way to do this would be to use inheritance: you'd create a subclass of `LinkedList`, and override the `add()` method:

```
class MyLinkedList<E> : LinkedList<E>() {
    override fun add(e: E)
        = super.add(e).also{ println(e) }
}
```

(I've used the Kotlin `also()` function to simplify this a bit.  The alternative would be to call the superclass method, store the result in a temporary value, do the logging, and then return the temporary value…)

The idea is easy enough.  But there are quite a few hidden problems with this approach…

For example: if you've tried to be thorough, you'd also spot that there are other ways to add elements to the list: there's a second `add()` method which lets you specify the position as well.  And there are two `addFirst()` and two `addAll()` methods as well.  So you override those as well.

But then you find that sometimes items are getting logged *twice*…  And after some investigation, you discover why: in `LinkedList`, the implementation of one of the `addAll()` methods simply calls the other one.  (If someone calls your first `addAll()` method, that logs and then calls the superclass method; that calls the other, but because you've overridden that too, it logs *again* before calling *that* superclass method.)

This is the main problem: **you don't just need to know the public interface of the class you're inheriting from, you also need to know the private details of how it's implemented too.**

In the case of the Java stdlib you're lucky, because Oracle publish the source code.  (If it's a third-party library, you may be less lucky.)  So you could work around this by only overriding one of the two `addAll()` methods.

But this isn't a proper solution.  What if Oracle change the implementation in a future version?  (This isn't a theoretical problem; it happens a lot in practice!)

This is known as the [fragile base class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) problem, and there are no really good ways around it.  **Unless you control the superclass too, subclassing isn't safe: it's far too easy to leave hidden problems, and for your code to break if the superclass changes.**

So what's the alternative to this?  Delegation.

Instead of creating a subclass, you write a separate implementation of the `List` interface; your class contains an instance of `LinkedList`, and all your methods simply call the methods on that instance — except for the `add…()` methods, which also do your logging, e.g.:

```
class MyLinkedList<E>(val delegate: LinkedList<E>) : List<E> {
    fun add(e: E)
        = delegate.add(e).also{ println(e) }
    // ...similar for the other add methods...

    override val size = delegate.size
    override fun get(index: Int) = delegate.get(index)
    // ...similar for all the remaining List methods...
}
```

This is much safer.  It doesn't matter if the `LinkedList` you're delegating to calls its own methods; that won't have any effect on your code.  Your class is insulated from the internal details of `LinkedList`, and from changes to it.  Great!

So why isn't delegation used more often?  Because in Java and similar languages, it's very long-winded.  As you can see from the above, not only do you have to write implementations of the `add…` methods you're interested in; you also have to write implementations of every other method in the interface, all just forwarding those calls to your delegate instance.  That's a lot of boilerplate in every case, but `java.util.List` has about 30 public methods!  (And of course that introduces a new type of fragility: if any new methods get added to the interface, your code will break until you add them in.)

Very painful.

But not in Kotlin!  Kotlin gives you the benefit of delegation *without* having to write all that boilerplate!  You simply tell it what interface you're implementing, and what instance you want to delegate to, and it'll automatically generate all the necessary forwarding methods!  You just override the ones you want, and it does the rest!

```
class MyLinkedList<E>(val delegate: LinkedList<E>) : List<E> by delegate {
    fun add(e: E)
        = delegate.add(e).also{ println(e) }
    // ...similar for the other add methods...
}
```

So you get the best of both worlds: **you can write Kotlin code that's as simple and concise as the traditional subclassing approach, but with all the safety and robustness of delegation — and without the breaking if the interface changes, either.**

Comment: Very good write up!