# Override kotlin operator extension function in subclass

Tags: kotlin, types, operator-overloading, extension-methods

I am trying to write my own subclass of LinkedHashMap that executes some additional functionality on update. This looks something like the following:

```
class MyMap(): LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {
    operator fun set(key: String, value: String) {
        super.put(key, value)
        doSomethingWith(value)
    }
}
```

I then declare a variable of type `MutableMap<String, String>` and assign an object of type `MyMap` to it:

```
val myMap: MutableMap<String, String> = MyMap()
```

However, if I now try to use my modified operator method

```
myMap["key"] = "value"
```

the method I wrote is not called, but the extension function defined for MutableMap in kotlin (`kotlin/collections/Maps.kt`) is. This part I don't understand, since the declared type of my variable is an interface (so statically resolving the method should not be possible), and the dynamic type is `MyMap`, which defines the `set` operator and doesn't have an extension function for it (which should either way not be able to hide an actual implementation in the class itself). If I declare the static type of my variable as `MyMap`, my function is called as expected. Why does Kotlin resolve the function via the parent class if the declared type of my variable is different?

DISCLAIMER: I am going to solve this problem by overriding the `put` function, so my question is less about a concrete solution and more about finding an explaination for this imo weird behavior.

Comment: Are you aware that [`MutableMap.set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set.html) is an extension function? Your `set` doesn't actually override anything.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, as I wrote in my question I know that - it's still shadowed by the extension function, which is what is weird to me

Comment: Don't create a subclass; although that's an obvious approach, it has [hidden dangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class). Much safer to use [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565400/10134209) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `set` method does not `override` anything in any of its superclasses or any of the interfaces it implements, so dynamically resolving to your `set` method through the `MutableMap` interface is not possible in the first place. In fact, there is no instance method `set` in the hierarchy for you to override. [`set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set.html) is an extension function!

```
operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V)
```

Basically, the above extension function and the `set` you wrote are two unrelated callables. The compiler only sees the former when the compile time type is `MutableMap`.

It resolves to *your* `set` when the compile time type is `MyMap` because it always prioritises non-extension functions over extension functions. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#call-with-an-explicit-receiver) for the exact priorities.

In this case, you *can* actually override (in the general sense, not `override`) the built-in `set` by just redeclaring your own extension *with the same signature*:

```
operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V) {
    ...
}
```

This is because extension functions in the package scope and explicitly imported extension functions has a higher priority than *implicitly imported* extension functions. The built-in `set`, being in the `kotlin.collections` package, is implicitly imported.

But if you want dynamic resolution, that's not going to work.

Comment: I get that `get` is an extension function - but it's an extension function of LinkedHashMap, not MutableMap (which is an interface), and LinkedHashMap doesn't occur anywhere except for it being the superclass of my class

Comment: @Lukor What do you mean by " it's an extension function of LinkedHashMap"? Do you mean that its receiver can be a `LinkedHashMap`? Well yes, but that doesn't mean you can override it. You can only override `open` functions that are declared in `LinkedHashMap`, [and `set` is not declared in `LinkedHashMap`.](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ea836fd46a1fef07d77c96f9d7e8d7807f793453/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L249)

Comment: I now see my problem (which is that I can't read :p): I could've sworn the function that was called was `LinkedHashMap<K, V>.set`, but it actually is `MutableMap<K, V>.set` as you said, hence my confusion. This now makes a lot more sense, because that just means that the function is resolved statically.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declared your variable as `MutableMap<String, String>`

Just changing this line

```
val myMap: MutableMap<String, String> = MyMap()
```

to

```
val myMap = MyMap()
```

or

```
val myMap : MyMap = MyMap()
```

should solve it

Comment: this is what I wrote in my question - MutableMap is an interface, so this should imo not have an influence on which method is called, and my question is why does it